# Query on same column with different condition - groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a transaction table like this :

```
  acct_id      trans_type         date_of_tran
-------------------------------------------------
     A          WITHDRAW          2021-Jun-20
     A          DEPOSIT           2021-Jun-21
     A          DEPOSIT           2021-Jun-22 

     B          WITHDRAW          2021-Jun-20
     B          WITHDRAW          2021-Jun-21

     C          DEPOSIT           2021-Jun-20
     C          DEPOSIT           2021-Jun-21
     C          WITHDRAW          2021-Jun-21
     C          WITHDRAW          2021-Jun-21
```

I want to find out which accounts have only WITHDRAWN money  but have not deposited any  within a specific time duration .

Example - Account B has only withdrawn money - no deposite within Jun20-21

**strong text**

Comment: Hint: `EXISTS(...)` and  `NOT EXISTS(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the rows with `trans_type` 'WITHDRAW' from `transaction_table` then ignore the accounts for which `DEPOSIT` transaction is available with the help of `not exists`

```
select * from transaction_table  tt
where trans_type='WITHDRAW'
and not exists
              (
                  select 1 from transaction_table tt1 
                  where tt.acct_id=tt1.acct_id and trans_type='DEPOSIT'
                  and date_of_tran >= '2021-Jun-20' and 2021-Jun-20<='2021-Jun-21'
              );
```

Comment: This worked with little bit change in the filter criteria .
Marking as accepted answer !Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome. Hope you got your job done. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of rows per account id and compare it to the number of WITHDRAW lines. If they're the same, the account has only withdrawals

```
SELECT acct_id 
FROM transaction
WHERE date_of_tran BETWEEN '2021-06-20' AND '2021-06-21'
GROUP BY acct_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN trans_type = 'WITHDRAW' THEN 1 END)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/60447/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation, like this:

```
select acct_id
from transactions
where date_of_tran >= ? and date_of_tran < ?
group by acct_id
having min(trans_type) = 'WITHDRAW';
```

This uses the fact that `'DEPOSIT' < 'WITHDRAW'`.

Comment: This looks interesting , can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: @KMD . . . What needs elaboration?  If the only possible values are `'DEPOSIT'` and `'WITHDRAW'` and the *minimum* value is `'WITHDRAW'`, then there are no `'DEPOSIT'` values.

Answer (score 0):

this may not be elegant, but at least it's easy to understand :-)

```
SELECT aa
FROM   t
WHERE  cc < '2021-Jun-22'
       AND cc > '2021-Jun-19'
GROUP  BY aa,
          bb
HAVING bb = 'WITHDRAW'
EXCEPT
SELECT aa
FROM   t
WHERE  cc < '2021-Jun-22'
       AND cc > '2021-Jun-19'
GROUP  BY aa,
          bb
HAVING bb = 'DEPOSIT'
```

where

```
aa = acct_id      
bb = trans_type         
cc = date_of_tran
```